# Python - Importing module gets global variables

Tags: python, module, global, python-import

I have two Python scripts, one testclass.py:

```
import numpy
zz = numpy

class Something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.xp = zz
```

and one testscript.py:

```
from testclass import Something
x = Something()
print(x.xp)
```

I expected testscript.py to throw an error because I thought that testscript only imports the class `Something` (with its `__init__` method), and not the global variable `zz`. So, given this bevahiour, my question is, when importing from a module, does Python "run" everything in the module file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When you execute:

```
from testclass import Something
```

It has the same effect as:

```
import testclass
Something = testclass.Something
```

More generally, the Python interpreter can't know beforehand what objects your module exposes (unless you explicitly name them in [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)). For an extreme case, consider the following:

`a.py`:

```
import random

if random.random() > 0.5:
    class Foo(object):
        pass
else:
    class Bar(object):
        pass
```

Running `from a import Foo` has a 50% chance of failing because the `a` module object may or may not have a `Foo` attribute.

Comment: I like the idea of defining random stuff in a module deep in your project. Preferably keeping the same name, but a different MRO, would make for fun times.

Comment: Will executing `from a import Foo` multiple times increase/decrease the chance of failing? Or will the defined class remain the same during the process after the first import?

Comment: @ZachGates: The module object is cached in `sys.modules` after it's first 
imported.